# Spaces that are contractible mod diagonal

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, terminology

I bumped into a seemingly natural strengthening of contractibility, which I refer to as "contractible mod diagonal". I'd like to know if this is something standard and whether it appears somewhere or has some applications. A short definition is that $X$ is contractible mod diagonal if the diagonal is a strong deformation retract of $X \times X$, though I prefer to state the definition differently, and state the above as a characterization (see below) to explain the name and to explain why I see it as a contractibility property of $X$ itself (and also because I came up with this characterization only when writing this post).

> Lemma. A topological space $X$ is contractible if and only if the two projections $\pi_1, \pi_2 : X \times X \to X$ are homotopic.

Proof. One of the equivalent definitions for a topological space $X$ to be contractible is that any two maps $h_1, h_2 : Y \to X$ are homotopic. This gives "only if". Another equivalent definition is that there is a homotopy between the identity map and the constant map at $x_0 \in X$. This gives "if". Square.

Taking the homotopy of $\pi_1, \pi_2$ as the standard meaning of contractible, we say $X$ is *contractible mod diagonal* if $\pi_1, \pi_2 : X \times X \to X$ are homotopic mod diagonal, in the sense that there is a homotopy $h : I \times X \times X \to X$ between them such that the restriction $h|_{I \times \Delta_X}$ is the projection to second (equivalently third) coordinate. Here $\Delta_X = \{(x, x) \;|\; x \in X$ is of course the diagonal.

> Lemma. A topological space $X$ is contractible mod diagonal if and only if $\Delta_X$ is a strong deformation retract of $X \times X$.

Proof. Suppose $h : I \times X \times X \to X \times X$ is a strong deformation retraction to the diagonal. Then define $g(x, y) = \pi_1(h(1, x, y))$. Then $\pi_1 : X \times X \to X$ is homotopic to $g$ by $h'(t, x, y) = \pi_1(h(t, x, y))$. Similarly, $\pi_2 : X \times X \to X$ is homotopic to $\pi_2(h(t, x, y))$, and of course we have $\pi_1(h(1, x, y)) = \pi_2(h(1, x, y))$ so $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are homotopic by transitivity.

On the other hand suppose $\pi_1, \pi_2$ are homotopic mod diagonal by $h : I \times X \times X \to X$. A strong deformation retraction to the diagonal is given by the formula $h'(t, x, y) = (h(t/2, x, y), h(1-t/2, x, y))$. Square.

> Question. Is there a standard name for this notion (as a property of $X$)? Or a reference where it pops up?

I know there is SDR-contractibility, meaning there is a strong deformation retract to some point of $X$. Of course if $h : I \times X \times X \to X$ is a contraction mod diagonal, then $h'(t, x) \mapsto h(t, x, x_0)$ is a strong deformation retraction to $\{x_0\}$ for any $x_0$. There are standard examples of spaces which are SDR-contractible, but only to some points $x_0$ and not all, so my notion is not equivalent to SDR-contractible already for that reason. I don't know if it is equivalent to every point being a strong deformation retract, but I doubt this.

The property is not trivial: If $X$ is a convex subset of Euclidean space, then $X \times X$ contracts to the diagonal by linear interpolation $h(t, x, y) = x + t(y - x)$, so convex subsets of Euclidean spaces are contractible mod diagonal.

I looked for such a notion only in a few haphazard places: I took a glance at the 59 instances of "diagonal" in Hatcher's book, and checked the "contractible space" entry on the topospaces wiki. As I love chasing geese, I also asked chatGPT about $X \times X$ strong deformation retracting to the diagonal, and it claims that people have used the names "diagonal deformation retract", "diagonal retract", "diagonally contractible", and "strongly homotopy self-equivalent" for this notion. Unfortunately I as unable to verify any of them.

Comment: The property is known as `equiconnectedness' and is well-studied.

Comment: Thanks! It seems this concept appears on the very wiki I looked at https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Equiconnected_space but unluckily for me, they don't make the link to contractibility. (Like last time, if you copy that to an answer, I'll accept.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The property is known as *equiconnectedness* and is well-studied.

Originally, a local version of this property was introduced by Fox,

> R. Fox, [*On Fibre Spaces II*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-49/issue-10/On-fibre-spaces-II/bams/1183505423.full), Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. **49** (10) (1943), 733-735.

Here, a space $X$ is **locally equiconnected** if the projections $\pi_1,\pi_2:X\times X\rightarrow X$ are homotopic relative $\Delta_X$ over some neighbourhood $V$ of the diagonal. This is the same as the property which almost a decade later Serre would call **ULC**,

> J. P. Serre, *Homologie Singuliere Des Espaces Fibres*, Ann. Math. **54** No. 3. (1951), 425-505.

The earliest paper I could find where a space is defined to be **equiconnected** if it admits a local equiconnecting structure in which the neighbourhood $V$ is all of $X\times X$ is maybe Himmelberg's paper

> C. Himmelberg, [*Some Theorems on Equiconnected and Locally Equiconnected Spaces*](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1965-115-00/S0002-9947-1965-0195038-X/S0002-9947-1965-0195038-X.pdf), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. **115** (1965), 43-53.

Comment: Now the topospaces wiki knows about this connection too https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Contractible_space#Stronger_properties